# Maximum likelihood estimation and sampling bias, application of class weights

Tags: maximum-likelihood, survey-weights

If I train a model (e.g. a neural net) via maximizing the likelihood function on a given training set, then do I need to adjust for sampling bias?

Let me give you an example for a classification task (where the cross entropy loss would be used to maximize the likelihood). I want to classify people into group $y \in\{ A,B\}$ depending on their answers $x$ in a survey. However,
the training data $\{x,y\}$ were generated in a biased manner, e.g. via a survey and survey sampling
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survey_sampling such that 1000 people of group A and 1000 people of group B were asked - although the probability of finding a person of group A in the population is 99% and the probability of finding a person of group B in the population is only 1%.

Should I adjust in the training of my neural net for this biased sampling via e.g. setting sample weights such that the samples of class A have 99% weight and the samples of class B have 1 weight?

Can one make an argument that setting these class weights makes the trained model a maximum aposteriori estimator? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation
Is there literature or is this just too obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd have to adjust sampling bias just to estimate the mean, such as the Horvitz Thompson estimator. Why should it be any different from a neural net?

Comment: I am asking from a process optimization point of view. Let s say a machine is run according to 2 receipts (which gives the sampling bias), resulting in some data x, y being gathered and where y is then either good=1 or bad=0 . If I want to predict how a machine would perform outside of the frequently reused setpoint regions, I am having some trouble because of the sampling character which results in arbitrary replication of experiments. How should I do ML then? Should I perform some kind of blocking/clustering/subsampling of these highly correlated measurements?My thoughts are a bit fuzzy

Comment: Having searched again gave this pdf "The sample bias correction technique commonly used in [ML] consists of reweighting the cost of an error on each training point of a biased sample to more closely reflect the unbiased distribution. 
Sample Selection Bias Correction Theory - Google Research". In the most extreme case of sampling bias the training data distribution does not reflect the true distribution and then the model would need to make out of training data distribution predictions. Prior knowledge would have to injected for truly fixing it.

Comment: If you're doing maximum likelihood, weight the likelihood according to the inverse of the sampling probability. It's really not more complicated than that.